# database wont change on DNS server when changing the connection string

Tags: string, mongodb, server, dns, connection

so i have a DNS server with my code running on it. when first depolyed the server it was running with a free cluster from mongodb but now i changed the free cluster to a mongodb running on the DNS server. i changed the connection string and it works locally just fine. but when pulling the changes with SSH to my DNS server it still takes the data from the old free cluster although notihng inthe code points into it. i have tried to check if changes are happening when pulling from ssh and they are. just the database connection stay with the old one. what could be the problem? should i restart the server or some service?